# jQuery - Fancybox: I can't hide the image after enlarging the thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like get the image from server and dynamically show it in the website. And then I can enlarge it when clicking. My code works on IE, however, it doesn't work on firefox:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();

/*
 *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
 */

$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
    prevEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect : 'none',

    closeBtn  : false,
    arrows    : false,
    nextClick : true,

    helpers : {
        thumbs : {
            width  : 50,
            height : 50
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
And the ajax code for uploading image is the following:

```
function ajaxFileUpload() {
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url : 'upload', 
    secureuri : false, 
    fileElementId : 'file1',
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'HTML', 
    success : function(data, status) 
    {
        var arr=new Array(); 
        arr = data.split(",");

        $("#div_Image").append("<a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='thumb' href='" + arr[1] + "'><img src='" + arr[0] + "' alt='' /></a>"); 
        $("#file1").removeAttr("required");
        if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
            if (data.error != '') {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }
    },
    error : function(data, status, e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
})
return false;}
```

If I use it as a static method, it works again. like that:

```
    <a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='thumb' href='1441863951636.jpg'><img src='small_1441863951636.jpg' alt='' /></a>
```

I know that there should be some wrongs, but I can't figure out. Could guys help me fix the problem.